# Height of options messed up after shown

Tags: jquery, html, css

Here is my select box

```
<div id="paym" style="display: none;"><center><select id="payments2" name="payments2" style="width:90%; text-align: left;">
    <option value="" data-description="Exchange To">Processor</option>
    <?php
         $processor = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `processors`");
         while($pro = $processor->fetch_assoc()){
    ?>
           <option value="<?php echo $pro['id']; ?>" data-image="<?php echo $pro['icon']; ?>"><?php echo $pro['name']; ?></option>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
</select></center></div>
```

it populates with about 12 options, not that, that really matters.

Then I have this `function`

```
$('#payments').on("change", function(){
        $('#paym').show();
 });
```

When the first my div `payments` changes it does show my new select box, but when you click it, it is super small. see image below

[image: small]

but if I close the option menu and reopen, it is the right size, see image

[image: big]

So basically what I am trying to figure out is how to get it to be the right size the first time, instead of having to close the box and then re-open it. I have tried making my `height` bigger but it didn't do anything but create white space.

Here is a JS fiddle with everything that I use to create the select boxes, there are external sources added
http://jsfiddle.net/fLqym36j/1

Comment: Make a Fiddle with some testdata

Comment: what `#payments` is? maybe it must be `#payments2` in js?

Comment: @AndrewEvt it's another `select` but it has no bearing considering it is not causing the issue because it is doing what it is supposed to do

Comment: Are you using some js module, to make options `designed`? If it have some `init()` function, maybe try to call it before `$('#paym').show();`. Or check your scripts loading statuses, maybe you open select very fast, and some code is still loading

Comment: @Patrick2607 http://jsfiddle.net/fLqym36j/

Comment: @AndrewEvt I have updated the question to include a jsfiddle link so you can see what I am working with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving the second call to `msDropdown` in the event handler, like so

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#payments').on("change", function(){
    $('#paym').show();
    $("#payments2").msDropdown({visibleRows:4});
  });
  $("#payments").msDropdown({visibleRows:4});
});
```

I don't know what's going on in that script but the fact that `#paym` is hidden at first is probably causing the issue.

[Here's the updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fLqym36j/2/)

Keep in mind this is only one way you can ensure that the second drop down display's properly.  What you want to keep in mind is that the script should run on an element that has layout, eg isn't hidden or `display: none;`.  Whether that means hiding the dropdown *after* it's been initialized, or initializing the dropdown once the element is visible, or any other option, is up to you.